# Bootstrap selectable table

Tags: html, jquery

I am trying to create a selectable table with bootstrap.
Let's say I have a row like this:

```
<tr><th class="ui-widget-content">Login ID</th><th>Rank</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th></tr>
```

and that's the javacript part:

```
$("#table").selectable({
     stop: function(){
        var selection = $("#select-result").empty();
        $(".ui-selected",this).each(function(){
           selected_id = $(this).text();
        });
     }
});
```

Can anyone explain why it returns the whole row and not just the "LoginID"?
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: try `$('#table tr')` as selector

Comment: It seams to work but only for thead. What should I write to focus on tbody?

Comment: `$('#table tbody tr')`